# Sublime Text cppcheck "no lint errors"

Tags: sublimetext3, cppcheck, sublimelinter

I installed sublime linter, cppcheck for sublime linter and cppcheck binaries. I've set up cppcheck like the other linters (for php and javascript) but cppcheck is not working. In the command line it says

```
SublimeLinter: cppcheck activated: Extensions\cppcheck\cppcheck.exe
```

But linter is not working. Clicking on "show lint errors" gives

```
no lint errors
```

And I'm sure that there are errors in the code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've met the similar problem as you described.
Here's some advice:

1. read the '.eslintrc' file clearly;
2. try to run 'eslint xxx' in the terminal and find out if there is any hints or errors;
3. reopen the sublimetext and traverse your project to find out any lint warnings ；
4. click the lint warnings you found and you'll be surprised to find that the lint works.

I guess it may caused by the linter's error.